# How to Evaluate a Probability Density Function you Fitted?

Tags: density-function, model-evaluation

I was reading "A Student's Guide to Bayesian Statistics" by Ben Lambert and he brought up something I never thought of before and can't find the answer to on Google. That is, evaluating a PDF.

In machine learning, you fit a model to training data, and evaluate it on testing data. What do you do for a probability model you fit? (like a normal distribution)

So, to be specific:

1. You have training and testing data.
2. You fit a Normal Distribution to the training data using MLE or something.
3. How do you know if it would simulate accurate data in the future?
4. Use the testing data to evaluate the PDF somehow

My guess is that you could simulate 1000 datapoints or something in the PDF, and then compare that data to the testing data to see how similar it is.

If the simulated datapoints (sampled from the PDF) is similar to the testing data, then it's a good fit?

What is the standard to evaluate a PDF?

Comment: Look up the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.  You’ll have to bootstrap the critical values if you’re estimating the pdf’s parameters from the data.  See this post for why: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/471990/231666

Comment: Thanks, I thought that KS-test was for seeing how well a model fits data? I mean I could use that to decide on a model (exponential, normal etc.) to fit the training data, but is it accepted practice to use it as a method to asses the model on testing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comparing multiple models then you can compare them in the exact same way you would in machine learning, by computing the predictive likelihood of a hold-out test set. The AIC (commonly used for model selection) is an approximation to the out-of-sample predictive likelihood in certain models, but in most cases its probably best to use an actual test set instead.

If you only have a single model and you want to know whether it provides a good fit to a dataset, then this can be achieved by goodness-of-fit testing (frequentist) or using something like posterior p-values (Bayesian). In both cases you are essentially testing whether the observed data "looks like" typical data simulated from the fitted model, where the definition of "looks like" is done via an appropriately chosen test statistic/distance function.